# Symfony: collection validation through Valid and Count constraints

Tags: validation, symfony, symfony-forms, orocrm, symfony-validator

Today i faced strange issue with form collection validation (symfony 2.7.3)

I have validation.yml configured to validate BusinessTrip form. This form contains a field with collection of BusinessTripUser forms to specify users and their business trip targets.

**The problem:**

When i try to save BusinessTrip form with several users added to collection there is a validation error sayin' that i must specify minimum one user for this business trip (Count constraint).
But there are several users already.

If i disable Count constraint (comment it in validation.yml) everything works ok, users are successfully validated with Valid constraint. But i need this validation.
Maybe someone already met and solved this problem?

**The source:**

```
OQ\BusinessTripBundle\Entity\BusinessTrip:
    properties:
        users:
            - Valid: ~
            - Count:
                min: 1
                minMessage: Specify at least one employee 

OQ\BusinessTripBundle\Entity\BusinessTripUser:
    properties:
        description:
            - NotBlank:
                message: Specify the employee role in this business
        user:
            - NotNull:
                message: Specify the employee
```

Comment: Take a debugger and debug why a validator fires (that's what one usually is supposed to do when their code does not work as expected).

Comment: sorry, that was not an Symfony problem, look at my post below

Answer (score 0):

Solved

Client-side validation mechanism (jQuery Validate Plugin) of my project cannot handle correctly Count constraint against collection field. So, it is not a symfony issue.

Now i implemented this check via getter constraint and corresponding method that check if any user exist in the ArrayCollection. And this check works perfect, but in backend.